# need backup of partitions

Tags: linux

I've got some partitions (with /home) on my second disk and I'm having some problems with him so I chose to trash it. But is there any possibility of remounting home from this disk to my first one with linux core?

Comment: I do not clearly see the organisation of your disks. You have disk A and disk B, how many partition (A1, A2... B1, B2...?) on each? with what data (A1 = system root, A2 = home directories ...)? and which do you want to mount where?

Comment: I want to move data from B to A, but B got mounting points.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming LVM is not in use, you can just use `mount` as root to mount the partitions in any directory you choose. If LVM is in use then you may need to run `vgchange` and `lvchange` as necessary to activate the other VG/LVs first.

```
mount /dev/sdb7 /mnt/otherhome
mount /dev/OtherVG/SomeLV /mnt/home
```